# Is my phone destroying my sd card?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, link2sd

Recently, whenever I install an application on my phone, I get a notification: "blank SD card detected", then I will have to repair it using a computer.

I tried using another SD card but the problem persisted. I didn't have this problem before I rooted my phone. Instead, all media files will be deleted.

I tried formatting both the phone and the SD card (using Ubuntu), but the problem persisted. I installed an antivirus but it is useless.

Note: I have installed Link2SD to gain more space and I think it might be the problem: The ext2 partition works fine but the fat32 will always crash. I get:

> SD card blank or has unsupported file system.

I can format the SD card so it works but whenever I install anything the error will come back. What is the solution?

Comment: Looks like the problem lies in the custom ROM. Can you flash another ROM in to it? (or try resetting the existing ROM again.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a very common problem among Android-based smartphones. 
I had a Samsung S3 (or GT-i9300 if you prefer) and it burned six microsd cards...
I tried doing a factory reset (since I had a custom rom) but nothing changed. Thought it was the microsd manufacturer, so I began buying expensive and faster cards but, again, nothing changed. Then I returned the phone to Samsung but they told me nothing was wrong. 
After nine months of memory cards being broken at a speed unknown by human race, I decided to sell the S3 and move to another company (Google and their various Nexus products): I don't have the chance to expand the memory with an external card, but at least I don't have to spend hundreds of dollars to buy new sds xD

BTW the only reason I can think of is that moving an app to the sd requires the phone to continually read data from the card, causing an over-heating situation that damages it...

Comment: Seconded. Reading from a card leads to overheating. Not sure it's Samsung to blame, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in partitioning the sd card itself. Some phones/sd cards are not compatible with such change and hence your sd card will be destroyed as long as you keep partitioning it.